# Creating a dynamic form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I need to create a form which has 2(Yes/NO) options and if the user clicks one of the option then he should get a collapsing subform with more specifics regarding to that particular selection. If he selects other option then he should get another collapsing subform with related info. I know that we have to use JavaScript or Jquery(to get the collapsing effect), but I am new to both. Any simple tutorials or info for beginners is greatly appreciated.

PS: I have seen many questions for this requirement but the fact is me being a beginner makes it tough to understand them.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you are going to need to wrap the two different subforms in divs and then use the jQuery .show() and .hide() functions to show and hide them when the right radio button is clicked.

Here is a useful tutorial on showing and hiding: http://papermashup.com/simple-jquery-showhide-div/

EDIT: More specific answer for user..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#check-box").click( function(){
     if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
         $('#div1').show();
     } else {
        $('#div1').hide();
     }
  });
```

});

Comment: No problem! I'd always appreciate you marking it as answering your question if you think it did, but either way, glad I could help!

Comment: Hey Jesse, I wanted to show the div if user chooses 1 radio button to other. but its not working is the method `.click` support checking or radio buttons? or there is some other material like `if value ="1" then show()` something like that... Your link was helpful but I couldnt find a method for check boxes nor radio buttons. Can you help me with that.

Comment: That should work for check boxes (and should be easily adaptable for radio boxes).

Comment: Thank you So much. Btw what books do you recommend to learn jqeury.

Comment: Hi Jesse, When I 1st select the Y option & then change it to N option in the Y/N answer question the two subforms that I have get concatenated how can I make them as mutually exclusive events. What more do I need to add to my JS(which is same as the fiddle that you showed).

Answer (score 3):

You have to render the entire form and hide all the subforms, each with a different ID. Depending on the button/choice pressed, you call `$.show()` on the corresponding `div` with code like this:

```
$("#choice1_subform").click(function(){
    $("#div1").show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Shouldn't I bother about using the hide() function? like Jesse Pollak has described below?

Comment: Yes. If you click on another choice, it should `hide()` the previous subform and show the other.

Comment: I get an error in firebug saying $ is not defined in line `$("#element_4_1").click(function() {` Can you please tell me where I am going wrong

Comment: You probably didn't load jQuery in a `<script>` tag.

Comment: Hi Karlisson, I wanted to show the div if user chooses 1 radio button to other. but its not working is the method `.click` support checking or radio buttons? or there is some other material like `if value ="1" then show()` something like that...